# How to add slider in the wordpress index.php file?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

My javascript code for slider is as follows which is displayed in the
html format but     not displayed when I integrated it into a theme.This code is in header.php.I have     called all the requred js css and image files in it and that worked fine but the      problem is in slider portion.

```
Code in header.php

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
     $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        useCSS: Modernizr.touch
      });
  });
</script>

Code in index.php

<div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <div class="hero-unit">
            <h1>Affordable Hosting Solution</h1>
            <h3>Flathost is a bootstrap based responsive minimal, flat and afforable 
             hosting template with easy customization and great support</h3>
            <div class="slider-actions text-center"> <a href="features.html" class="btn
            btn-success btn-lg">Explore Features </a> <a href="pricing.html" class="btn
            btn-primary btn-lg">Plans and Pricing </a> </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="slide2">
            <p><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?
            >/images/server1.png" alt="server" class="img-responsive center-block"></p>
            <h1>Dedicated and VIP Hosting</h1>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="slide3">
            <p class="pull-left"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?
            >/images/server2.png" alt="server" class="img-responsive"></p>
            <h1>Managed Hosting</h1>
            <h3>Flathost is a bootstrap based responsive minimal, flat and afforable 
            hosting template with easy customization and great support </h3>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[thethe-image-slider name="flexslider"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Is it displaying the image?

Comment: No images in the slider are also not displayed.

Comment: Have you checked in that what path images are retrieving by Firebug or by inspect elements ? Check it once .